# GeoServer CSS - change size dynamically

Tags: point, style, scale, update, css

I have set point style with three different size, based on three different scale.

Is there any way to set one size and this one will increase or decrease automatically according with the scale (like QGIS already does)?

---

This is what I have:

```
@title  NAME
 * @abstract This is an abstract point layer.
 */
  [@sd < 275k] [@sd > 4k]
[APERTO='SI']
* {
   mark: symbol(circle);
   mark-size:2px;
   :mark {
     fill: #ffd700 ;
   }
 }

/* scale 750-4000 */
 @title  NAME
 * @abstract This is an abstract point layer.
 */
  [@sd < 4k] [@sd > 0.75k]
[APERTO='SI']
* {
   mark: symbol(circle);
   mark-size:6px;
   :mark {
     fill: #ffd700 ;
   }
 }
```

---

This is just a part of the code.

As you can see I have the same object with two different style, one for >4000 scale and one for <4000.

I was wondering if there is a way to have a dynamic value for scale, such as

```
mark-size: n/@sd
```

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: please show us what you have done so far and explain what exactly is not working for you

Comment: sorry. thank you for your clarification.

Comment: please take the [tour] and find out how this site works